# QTableView how to get the scroll bar row position

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qscrollarea

```
void scrollBarValueChanged(int value)
{
     int row = view->rowAt(value);
}
```

Such as the title, when the scroll bar rolling, how to get the scroll row index?

Comment: Do you just want to make sure that some row to be visible by scrolling the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [rowAt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#rowAt) and [columnAt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#columnAt) are exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use `horizontalScrollBar()` `verticalScrollBar()` functions and get scroll value from it.

```
QScrollBar *verticalScroll = ui->tableView->verticalScrollBar();
QScrollBar *horizontalScroll = ui->tableView->horizontalScrollBar();
int valueV = verticalScroll->value();
int valueH = horizontalScroll->value();
```

Also use `scrollTo` function to scroll to your table cell index. (horizontally and vertically)

```
ui->tableView->scrollTo( ui->tableView->model()->index(row,column) );
```

like this image:

```
ui->tableView->scrollTo(ui->tableView->model()->index(7,3));
```

[image: screenshot]

The [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) page on Qt website.